# Inline data.frame inclusion in R script

Tags: r

While there are functions for saving data as a separate CSV file (*write.table*) or as an R-data file (*save*, *saveRDS*), I have not found a way to store or print a data frame *as R code* that recreates this data frame.

Background of my question is that I want to include data with a script (instead of storing it in a separate file), and am thus looking for a way to generate the specific code provided the data frame already exists. I could hack on with *sed* or other external tools, but I wonder whether someone knows of a built-in method in R.

Comment: See `help("dput")` (as you would know if you had read the [top-voted R question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Great, that does the trick! Before posting,I had spent some time searching for an answer but did not search for "reproducible example".

Comment: You could also just have read the [tag:r] tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). ;)

Comment: Okay, I understood: shame on me! Nevertheless thanks for taking the trouble to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with "dput" like so:

```
dput(cars)
# Returns:
structure(list(speed = c(4, 4, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 
16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25), dist = c(2, 10, 4, 22, 16, 10, 18, 
26, 34, 17, 28, 14, 20, 24, 28, 26, 34, 34, 46, 26, 36, 60, 80, 
20, 26, 54, 32, 40, 32, 40, 50, 42, 56, 76, 84, 36, 46, 68, 32, 
48, 52, 56, 64, 66, 54, 70, 92, 93, 120, 85)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```